# Generate and show list with Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wrote a code for loading 2 Json files and to show the content on a website.
code is here

```
This is my code
https://pastebin.com/q61R9uLY
```

. The drinks.json (also in the link) have some cocktails with the ingridients in it. And the pump.json (also in the link on the bottom) my pump confoguration.

What i want?

How can I imrove my code. So the drinks.jsonshould be loaded and displayed with the cocktails but only if the cocktail is mixable with my current pump.json, so if the ingridents of the cocktail is configured on the pumps. I hope this is clear and you can help me. I don't want to use jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let show_drinks = drinks.filter(d=> {
  // get an array of the ingredients needed
  let e = Object.keys(d.ingredients).filter(i => {
    // get an array of the pumps and check each ingredient
    let d = Object.values(pumps).map(p => p.value.trim() == i.trim()).includes(true);
    // if the resulting array doesn't have at least one 'true' value, the ingredient isn't available in pumps
    return d
  }).length === Object.keys(d.ingredients).length
  // check that the length of found ingredients matches the original length we were searching for
  return e
})
```

```js
const drinks = [{"name": "Rum & Coke","ingredients": {"rum": 12,"coke": 48} }, {"name": "Gin & Tonic","ingredients": {"gin": 24,"tonic": 60}    }, {"name": "Long Island","ingredients": {"gin": 15,"rum": 15,"vodka": 15,"tequila": 15,"coke": 100,"osaft": 30}    }, {"name": "Screwdriver","ingredients": {"vodka": 50,"osaft": 150} }, {"name": "BeachSex","ingredients": {"vodka": 24,"osaft": 24,"anasaft": 48}   }, {"name": "Gin & Juice","ingredients": {"gin": 50,"osaft": 150}   }, {"name": "Tequila Sunrise","ingredients": {"tequila": 24,"osaft": 66}    }]
const pumps = {"pump_1": {"value": "rum", "name": "Pump 1", "pin": 17}, "pump_3": {"value": "tequila", "name": "Pump 3", "pin": 22}, "pump_2": {"value": "vodka", "name": "Pump 2", "pin": 27}, "pump_5": {"value": "anasaft", "name": "Pump 5", "pin": 24}, "pump_4": {"value": "osaft", "name": "Pump 4", "pin": 23}, "pump_7": {"value": "gin", "name": "Pump 7", "pin": 16}, "pump_6": {"value": "coke", "name": "Pump 6", "pin": 25}, "pump_8": {"value": "coke", "name": "Pump 8", "pin": 19}}

// here is the same code without all the comments
let show_drinks = drinks.filter(d=> Object.keys(d.ingredients).filter(i => Object.values(pumps).map(p => p.value.trim() == i.trim()).includes(true)).length === Object.keys(d.ingredients).length)
console.log(show_drinks, show_drinks.length, drinks.length)
```

Comment: @test1 - did this solution help solve your question? If so, please mark as the solution. Thanks